# Git repository not recognized anymore in virtual machine after PC crash

Tags: git

I got a VM with linux on my PC. The PC crashed. When I started the VM again and went to my git repository every command that I give with git produces the following error:

**fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git**

The .git folder still exits in the directory.

Does anyone know if this can be fixed without recreating the git repository?

Comment: The error message indicates that you're in the `.git` directory. `cd ..` to one directory higher. If that's not it, are your files still intact? Can you reinitialize a new repo onto the existing directory? Did you push the changes to a remote from where you can pull again? Anyway there are tons of resources online if you search the web for that exact error message, can you read [ask] and show what you have tried? Be sure to make a backup of the entire directory before you try anything else.

Comment: When VMs crash, bad things can happen (like your problem).  Honestly, if you didn't have any active work in your local Git, I would recommend just killing the folder, and cloning again.

Comment: It seems, that your local storage is not mounted on your VM anymore. Try to reboot your VM hard. (try not to save the state of the mashine, shut it down manual und restart it)